# Low rating of virtual pro GK due to very good team

Tags: fifa-14, virtual-pro, fifa-pro-club

I'm playing a virtual pro (offline and online carreer) as a goalkeeper in Fifa 14 and I found it quiet difficult to get a good rating, when your own team is very good. The rating keeps dropping (after the first contact to the ball, but not always?!) and when your team is very good in defending you won't get any contact with the ball. So you have no chance in getting a good rating at the end of the match. It's okay for onlinegames, but I need to get an average of 7,0 for my offline carreer and it's nearly impossible to get more then 5,5 when you are just watching your teammates and giving orders.

So my question is if there is anything I'm missing in beeing a good goalkeeper to get a decent rating (besides watching your goal)? Maybe it's just a bug that the rating keeps decreasing so fast?

PS: I'm playing on the PC if this is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really as in getting a 7.0. If you really want a good rating, just let your team give them a shot on goal. Having a save will improve your rating very fast. Also let them pass the ball more back to you. So you have more passes. Just also stay in position(not sure if there is a red circle on fifa 14 as well as a goalkeeper) Get out of the goal during a corner to save the ball.

Comment: So I need to manipulate the game or my team to play less aggressive, to get a better rating? In my opinion that can't be the right way. I hope that's not the final solution :( Thanks anyway mate

Comment: @Streuner No it just means, get more involved in their game. Eventually I think you will have to make some saves in a match so this doesn't apply on every match, but making saves is just the easiest way or else just try to get the ball more often.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but it can't be a good solution for this kind of problem. If my team is really good you will be forced to make bad passes or something so that they can get thorugh to take a shot. I played some (offline) matches and won't every game with 5 or more goals for my team and the opponent didn't get a shot in general. To leave such a match with a GK-rating of 4.8-5.5 is just frustrating and making the NPCs passing back isn't really nice for the gameplay itself I think. Nevertheless this is a valid solution/answer ;)

Comment: @Streuner Yeah well sorry to say but fifa kind of ruined it at some parts.

Comment: Indeed ;) I just thought I may made some mistakes in my gameplay.

Comment: @Streuner Like in real life, Neuer(Goalkeeper of Bayern Munich and Germany national team) never has to do anything. Probably always gets an average rating.

Answer (score 1):

For a change I observed a whole match between real Madrid and Barcelona. I also saw the replays where the goalkeepers stand when the ball is at different place on the pitch. I followed as the best possible way. Still no luck. Most importantly, the away matches are more pathetic. I did a things to get around 6.5 to 7 ratings on average in Home matches.

1. Playing a legendary or world class levels gives you more chances to save shots.
2. Following the ball. Wherever the ball is, just follow it standing in the box. Like, when ball is in the against half and your team is in possession, stand between penalty shootout point and penalty box. Similarly, when the ball is in opponent's half and against possession, stand between penalty shoot out point and 6 yard box. This does not drains your rating.
3. Last one is a bit of luck...At the 90th minute take the ball and allow a corner. Save the corner by coming out of the goal line and catching/ punching it. It gives a 1-1.5 rating hike. As the final whistle blows, it records the final rating which is now increased because of the last save.

Answer (score -1):

There is no other way then what Loko said!
Fifa 14 doesn't like goalkeeping, and doesn't want to improve the gameplay.
Another way to get a high rating is to turn down the settings, and upgrade the setting for CPU.
This way for example FC Bayern will be really bad again Ajax.
I am also a goalkeeper, and it pisses me off also to the fact that the goalkeepers lack the reflexes as 9 of the 10 goals I would block in real life.
There is no way to get the right position as goalkeeper, as there isn't any to find, except for when the opponent is getting close to the 16 meter line.